# Does record domain "include:" also refers to subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, dns-zone, dns-hosting, dmarc

I have a doubt setting up my SPF record. I would like to know if I set up an include record in the SPF record will also be "including" the subdomains of that principal domain that I have included?.

Let's take a look of an example in my doubt:

Example:

```
v=spf1 +include:example.com -all
```

Does this "+include:example.com" will be covering up also if my mail is sent from subdomain1.example.com or subdomain2.example.com ???

I really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `include` mechanism says "include the SPF record from example.com". Subdomains of example.com could have different SPF records which you would need to manually include if you wanted to trust those chains as well.

More information about the trust relationship and lookup ordering for include is at https://dmarcian.com/spf-syntax-table/#include.